# CSS :first-child selector IE7

Tags: css, internet-explorer-7, css-selectors

I've got little IE7 issue. I've got following CSS code and it does not work in IE7. However, .row [class*="span"] and :first-child both work if they are not combined. Is there a way to do something similar or make it work somehow?

```
.row [class*="span"]:first-child {
    margin-left: 0;
}
```

Comment: A bug in IE7? Impossibru

Comment: Why do you need to use the bracket selectors?

Comment: That's to select all objects with class span1, span2, etc...

Comment: Try using className instead of class

Comment: Ah. "If the closing square bracket of an attribute selector, ], is immediately followed by an element type selector, the rule is parsed as if there’s a descendant combinator—that is, a space—between the selectors, instead of failing as it should."

http://reference.sitepoint.com/css/css3attributeselectors

Comment: Just tired .row [className*="span"]:first-child, same thing, doesn't work. However .row [className*="span"] alone works...

Comment: Are you sure `[class*="span"]` is the first child?

Comment: @Torr3nt: Except there are no type selectors involved here. There's only a class, an attribute, and a pseudo-class.

Comment: It seems to be working in ie7 for me. http://tinkerbin.com/1VJm75kl

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If the first child *is* `[class*="span"]`, check to see if there's an HTML comment before it. If there is, [IE7 will mistakenly think the comment is the first child](http://reference.sitepoint.com/css/pseudoclass-firstchild), so it won't match the element you're looking for.

If you can't change the markup to delete the comment, you can work around it using the override technique I describe [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2717480/css-selector-for-first-element-with-class/8539107#8539107):

```
.row [class*="span"] {
    margin-left: 0;
}

.row [class*="span"] ~ [class*="span"] {
    margin-left: /* Reset the left margin for other elements */;
}
```

If you don't know the margin value to reset it to, you can try adding another selector that targets IE7's behavior with the `* + html` hack:

```
.row [class*="span"]:first-child, * + html .row :first-child + [class*="span"] {
    margin-left: 0;
}
```

`:first-child + [class*="span"]` matches that element if it follows exactly one comment node that's the first child in IE7.

Comment: You were right, I had comment just before first child... as soon as I removed it, started working.

Comment: As an automated workaround for IE7 `:first-child` and sibling combinator (`+`) bug, you can [remove comments as DOM nodes](http://tanalin.com/en/blog/2011/08/ie7-css-first-child-adjacent/) via JavaScript after page is loaded.